# Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="https://www.mytokenlocation.com", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.6.0)

Tags: hardhat

Im creating a NFTMARKETPLACE that  accepts user metadata and mint it as NFT, Ikeep failing at my test. this is my code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

//defining our storage

contract NFT is ERC721URIStorage {
    //using the counter utility
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    //for incrementing value of tokens
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    //the nft interacts with this contract address for txn
    address contractAddress;
uint256 newItemId;
    constructor(address marketPlaceAddress) ERC721("Metaverse Tokens", "METT") {
        contractAddress = marketPlaceAddress;
    }

    function createToken() public {
        //increment the count the nFT
        _tokenIds.increment();
        _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);

        //Get the current value of the token
        newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        //minting the NFT
    }
        
        function tokenURI (uint256 tokenId ) public view override returns (string memory TOKEN_URI){
        // _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        require(_exists(tokenId),"ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");
        return TOKEN_URI;
        }
function getTokenCounter() public view returns (uint256){

        //given the marketPlace permission to transact
        // setApprovalForAll(contractAddress, true);
        return newItemId;
}
}
```

This is my testing script

```
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
const { network, deployments, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")

!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip
    : describe("Nft Marketplace Unit Tests", function () {
          let nftMarketplace, nftMarketplaceContract, nftContractAddressConnect, nftContractAddress
          const PRICE = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1")
          const TOKEN_ID = 0

          beforeEach(async () => {
              accounts = await ethers.getSigners() // could also do with getNamedAccounts
              deployer = accounts[0]
              user = accounts[1]
              await deployments.fixture(["all"])
              nftMarketplaceContract = await ethers.getContract("NftMarketplace")
              nftMarketplace = nftMarketplaceContract.connect(deployer)
              nftContractAddress = await ethers.getContract("NFT")
              nftContractAddressConnect = await nftContractAddress.connect(deployer)
              await nftContractAddressConnect.mint("https://www.mytokenlocation.com")
              await nftContractAddressConnect.approve(nftMarketplaceContract.address, TOKEN_ID)
          })

          describe("listItem", function () {
              it("emits an event after listing an item", async function () {
                  expect(await nftMarketplace.listItem(nftContractAddressConnect.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)).to.emit(
                      "ItemListed"
                  )
              })
              it("exclusively items that haven't been listed", async function () {
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(nftContractAddressConnect.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  const error = `AlreadyListed("${nftContractAddressConnect.address}", ${TOKEN_ID})`
                  //   await expect(
                  //       nftMarketplace.listItem(nftContractAddressConnect.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  //   ).to.be.revertedWith("AlreadyListed")
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.listItem(nftContractAddressConnect.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith(error)
              })
              it("exclusively allows owners to list", async function () {
                  nftMarketplace = nftMarketplaceContract.connect(user)
                  await nftContractAddressConnect.approve(user.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.listItem(nftContractAddressConnect.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NotOwner")
              })
              it("needs approvals to list item", async function () {
                  await nftContractAddressConnect.approve(ethers.constants.AddressZero, TOKEN_ID)
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.listItem(nftContractAddressConnect.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NotApprovedForMarketplace")
              })
              it("Updates listing with seller and price", async function () {
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(nftContractAddressConnect.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  const listing = await nftMarketplace.getListing(nftContractAddressConnect.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  assert(listing.price.toString() == PRICE.toString())
                  assert(listing.seller.toString() == deployer.address)
              })
          })
```

This is my error
Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="https://www.mytokenlocation.com", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.6.0)

Comment: Obviously the error is when calling `nftContractAddressConnect.mint("https://www.mytokenlocation.com")`. Can you include the mint function code in the question?

Comment: function mintNft( string memory tokenURI) public  returns (uint256){
        _safeMint(msg.sender, s_tokenCounter);
        emit cardMinted(s_tokenCounter);
        s_tokenCounter = s_tokenCounter + 1;
    } Im trying to accept files from the front end and mint it as nft

Comment: The test calls `mint()` and not `mintNft()`, so you should fix the test to call the correct function instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider converting the string to its bytes32 representation using `ethers.utils.formatBytes32String (string yourShortString)` as specified in the [docs](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/strings/)